# BitLocker, USB-drive and GPO

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, bitlocker

I got myself into a difficult situation: enrypted USB-drive D: using an Windows PowerShell script file `*.ps1`.

```
Initialize-Tpm

#Enable Bitlocker 
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "D:" -RecoveryPasswordProtector -SkipHardwareTest

#Key upload to AD
$keyID = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint d: | select -ExpandProperty keyprotector | 
            where {$_.KeyProtectorType -eq 'RecoveryPassword'}
Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint d: -KeyProtectorId $keyID.KeyProtectorId
Enable-BitLockerAutoUnlock -MountPoint "D:"
```

But problem is that GPO for removable drives wasn't configured, so there is no recovery key in AD and the recovery key is now needed to unlock USB-drive.

Is there any other way?

Comment: The Bitlocker keys are usually stored with the computer object. Is the GPO configured for the PC? How are you trying to find the Bitlocker key?

Comment: GPO was cofigured for PC, but only for system and fixed drives. Removable disk part of GPO wasn't configured at all. Computer object contains only system drive recovery key.